# Summer '13 Web Service Endpoint Changes

Tags: apex, webservices

### Background

In the [Summer '13 Release Notes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf) on page 238 it states that web service endpoints in the form of `instance-api.salesforce.com` must be updated to the new format: `instance.salesforce.com`.

> **API Endpoint Changes**
>
> Prior to Summer ’13, API endpoints for web services used a hostname of the form instance-api.salesforce.com. API
>   endpoints now use a hostname of the form instance.salesforce.com. An example server endpoint URL from a SOAP
>   API connection might look like: https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/27.0/00DU0000000Q4f0.
>
> If you have any code that uses a hard-coded API endpoint, you’ll need to update this code. We recommend never hard-coding
>   the API endpoint and instead using the endpoint returned in the response to your initial connection to Salesforce. For example,
>   a SOAP API login() call returns a server URL endpoint that you can use for subsequent SOAP API calls.

### Question

Does this only apply to the [Standard Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm), or does it apply to custom [Apex Web Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods.htm) (created and generated within Salesforce)?

**For example...**

If I have a custom web service that I created in Salesforce that is consumed by a .Net application, the URL (in the web.config) looks something like this: `https://cs15-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/My_Web_Service`. Does it need to be updated? Also, note that the partner WSDL references: `https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0`.

Comment: I would imagine for both. It's best practice to not hardcode end points and use the URL that is returned with the Login Result as the Base URL for any further invocations.

Comment: LoginResult and friends will return the new format URLs but the old -api versions will continue to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that it does indeed effect both Apex Web Services and the Standard Web Service API end points. In either case as techtrekker points out, utilise the [LoginResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) ServerUrl element returned from the login operation to determine the correct end point to use and you'll be fine.